# Is an exponential family the same as an exponentially convex set?

Tags: probability-theory, information-geometry

An exponential family of probability distributions is usually defined as
$$
p(x) = e^{\theta\cdot f(x) \,-\, \psi(\theta)},
$$
where $\theta$ is a vector of parameters, $f(x)$ is some arbitrary vector-valued function of $x$, and $\psi= \log\sum_x e^{\theta\cdot f(x)}$, which ensures normalisation. This defines a set of probability distributions, one for each value of the parameter vector $\theta$. It's this set that's referred to as the exponential family.

Usually, $\theta$ seems to be assumed to be finite-dimensional, but I think this doesn't have to be the case. I'll assume for this question that it isn't, and the $\cdot$ could be any inner product, i.e. it could stand for an infinite sum or an integral rather than a finite sum.

One can also define an *exponentially convex set* of probability distributions in the following way: a set $C$ of probability distributions is exponentially convex if, for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
p \in C,q\in C \implies r\in C,
$$
where
$$
r(x) = e^{(1-\lambda)\log p(x) \,+\, \lambda \log q(x) \,-\, \psi(\lambda)},
$$
and $\psi = \log\sum_x e^{(1-\lambda)\log p(x) \,+\, \lambda \log q(x)}$. Note that I don't restrict $\lambda$ to between 0 and 1. One could equivalently define $r(x)$ as
$$
r(x) = \frac{1}{Z}p(x)^{1-\lambda}q(x)^\lambda.
$$

My question is, are exponential families and exponentially convex sets the same thing?

It's easy to show that all exponential families are exponentially convex sets, but what about the other direction? That is, if I have some set of distributions and I want to show that it's an exponential family, is it enough to show that it is exponentially convex in the above sense, or do there exist exponentially convex sets that are not exponential families?

If the answer is no, what would be a simple counterexample?

Comment: You'll have to have a more precise definition of "exponential family" if you want something to prove.

Comment: @kimchilover the precise definition of exponential family is part of the question - I don't have a rigorous textbook to hand, due to being at home over the holidays. But just out of interest, what do you find insufficiently precise about the definition I gave?

Comment: @kimchilover I made a guess about what might be confusing, and added some clarification

Comment: The usual definition of an exponential family does not require it to work for all values of $\theta$.  For example, the normal distributions with mean $0$ and unknown variance form an exponential family with $\theta = 1/\sigma^2$, but only for $\theta > 0$.  These would not form an exponentially convex set according to your definition, because it doesn't work for **all** $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Your words "it could stand for an infinite sum" are the trigger for me.  I want you to name the space in which $\theta$ lives.  Is it a Hilbert space, a topological vector space, or what?

Comment: I consider a question of form "construct a mathematical theory (that is, a new sub-branch of mathematics) such that so-and-so, and prove a result of shape this-and-that in it" to be inappropriate for a forum like MSE.  You are in effect asking us to write a research paper for you.

Comment: @kimchilover I am quite certain the answer to my question is known. I'm not asking anyone to invent anything, just to summarise a known result. It would be foolish for me to give an overly precise definition, because  I want an answer that follows the conventions of the field, which are not completely known to me.

Comment: @kimchilover I don't think that's a very realistic comment, nor a particularly kind or helpful one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think you are right. You could post that as an answer. (I am a bit surprised actually - I've always worked on the assumption that it should be defined for any value of $\theta$, but I've also always accepted that the normals are an exponential family, so I'm suffering from cognitive dissonance. Do you know anywhere accessible online where the full definition of an exponential family is given?)

Comment: Wikipedia's [Exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) adds that the supports of all distributions in the family should be the same, but says nothing about the domain of $\theta$. Which seems natural, when we define a parametric curve, say, it is unreasonable to prescribe the same parameter interval for all curves. It is, nonetheless, a good question if every exponentially convex set can be parametrized as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

(Reposted as an answer at OP's request)

The usual definition of an exponential family does not require it to work for all values of $\theta$.
For example, the normal distributions with mean $0$
and arbitrary variance form an exponential family with 
$\theta = 1/\sigma^2$,
but only for 
$\theta > 0$. These would not form an exponentially convex set according to your definition, because it doesn't work for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.